# Rails CoffeeScript carry out a command on load

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript file as part of a Rails application that looks like the following

```
    jQuery ->
      $ ->
        $('#secondthing').hide()

      $('#trips').change ->
        trips = $('#trip_quantity :selected').text()
        if trips == '1'
          $('#secondthing').hide()
        else
          $('#secondthing').show()
```

Now the part of the code that executes when trips changes works fine. However, the first bit of code that is menat to execute once the page has loaded does not change. I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: There's [nothing wrong](http://pastebin.com/8pq0LTZY) with the compiled code. Using `jQuery()` instead of `$()` is useless in that snippet, and the first hiding is placed in a useless function, however [everything works](http://jsfiddle.net/j8nZW/)

Comment: @Raffaele why would need `jQuery ->` and `$ ->` the answer below is correct

Comment: @DavidChase `$` is just a shortcut for `jQuery`, so there's no need to use both names in the same scope. Removing a "level" is ok from the code management perspective, but has no effect (as [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8nZW/) shows)

Comment: @Raffaele i know that is $ is a shortcut for jQuery thats why i said the answer below is correct b/c he removes the superfluous `$ ->` thats why you cant say theres "nothing wrong" when he's using the wrapper inside the same wrapper so in essence i agree with your statement i would however disagree with theres "nothing wrong", IMO improper technique is wrong

Comment: @DavidChase the code can be *improved*, but can't be *fixed*. He's not asking for a code review, he's asking for a solution to a bug. That's why suggesting removing a callback can't be **the answer**. It may be a comment, though. Then, the OP could improve the code sample, but the error still would stay on his side

Comment: @Raffaele gotcha makes sense, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with your code, so if it doesn't work the reason must be in the part you didn't show. However I'm pointing out a couple of things that apparently confuse people here.

First, there's no need to use both `jQuery` and `$` in the same scope. `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`, and the only scenario where both names make sense is when for compatibility reasons (with other versions of jQuery or maybe other libraries which also use  `$` as a shortcut) you encapsulate your code in a module like this:

```
(function($) {
  // Now $ is bound to whatever object you pass in
})(jQuery);
```

Given that we can freely substitute `$` for `jQuery` in your code, the next piece of misunderstanding is (compacted on a single line):

```
$ -> $ -> $("#foo").hide()
```

This snippet schedules a callback to be executed once the DOM is loaded. This callback in turn schedules another callback to hide `#foo` once the DOM is loaded. Since the second schedule is run when the DOM is already loaded, in practice it's executed immediately. That's why, even if you **should** really use

```
$ -> $("#foo").hide()
```

any extra "level" in the original code is no harmful, and in fact everything works [as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/J2h4m/). BTW, this is the most compact version of your code:

```
$ ->
  el = $("#secondthing")

  el.hide()

  $("#trips").change ->
    el[if $('#trip_quantity :selected').text() == '1' then "hide" else "show"]();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `$ ->` on your second line.

```
jQuery ->
  // $ ->
  $('#secondthing').hide()

  $('#trips').change ->
    trips = $('#trip_quantity :selected').text()
    if trips == '1'
      $('#secondthing').hide()
    else
      $('#secondthing').show()
```